# Three dimentional array of pointers where each dimention is different size in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

What I am trying to do is to define array of pointers, which each element points to array of pointers with different array size, which each element points to array of pointers with different array size, which each element points to structure.

I need something like this:

```
    array[10]->[12]->[8] = (structure*)malloc(sizeof(structure));
    array[9]->[16]->[2] = (structure*)malloc(sizeof(structure));
```

How to allocate memory and how to access this array members?

Javier.

Comment: What does your struct look like?

Comment: You'r question is verbalized confusiously. could you specifie your question? You want a §'d array that points to 3'd arrays?

Comment: And you want to use your structures as array, or you just want to store dynamic sized structures in that array?

Comment: The structure actually doesn't matter how it looks, for example, let it be typedef struct { int value; } structure;

Comment: but you want array to be array[x][y][z] or do you realy mean the acces operator ->?

Comment: I need an array where each member points to array with different size of array. The same for second level array - it points to array with different size of array. I dont know how more clear to define the question.

Comment: I used "->" operator just for demonstration, because I dont know how it should look like. Maybe is should be like this way ((void*)((void*)((void*)array[10])[12)[8]) = something.

Comment: well, so jsut look at my annswer. Thats what you are looking for. There you have an 3D array where each member can point anything, and you can request the allocated size of that member which it is pointing to by its structure element ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a jagged 3D array of pointers to a `struct`, such that for each `i` there can be a different number of `j`'s, and for each `j` there can be a different number of `k`'s.

Assuming that's the case, you could try something like this:

```
typedef struct { ... } structure;

structure ****arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * number_of_pages );
for( size_t page = 0; page < number_of_pages; page++ )
{
  arr[page] = malloc( sizeof *arr[page] * number_of_rows( page ));
  for ( size_t row = 0; row < number_of_rows( page ); row++ )
  {
    arr[page][row] = malloc( sizeof *arr[page][row] * number_of_cols( page, row ));
    for ( size_t col = 0; col < number_of_cols( page, row ); col++ )
    {
      arr[page][row][col] = malloc( sizeof *arr[page][row][col] );
    }
  }
}
```

You will want to add checks to make sure each `malloc` call succeeded; I left them out just to keep the code halfway readable.

This assumes the presence of a couple of functions, `number_of_rows` and `number_of_cols`, which return the number of rows for each "page" and the number of columns for each "page" and row, respectively.

`arr` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to your `struct` type; thus, the types of the various expressions are:

```
    Expression                   Type
    ----------                   ----
           arr                   structure ****
        arr[i]                   structure ***
     arr[i][j]                   structure **
  arr[i][j][k]                   structure *
 *arr[i][j][k]                   structure
```

You would access each member of the struct as

```
arr[i][j][k]->member;
```

**Edit**

Note that you'll have to deallocate the memory in the reverse order you allocated it:

```
for ( size_t page = 0; page < number_of_pages; page++ )
{
  for ( size_t row = 0; row < number_of_rows( page ); row ++ )
  {
    for (size_t col = 0; col < number_of_cols( page, row ); col++ )
    {
      free( arr[page][row][col] );
    }
    free( arr[page][row] );
  }
  free( arr[page] );
}
free( arr );
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want:

```
MyStruct*** ddd = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct**) * 2);

ddd[0] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct*) * 3);
ddd[0][0] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 2);
ddd[0][1] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 1);
ddd[0][2] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 4);

ddd[1] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct*) * 1);
ddd[1][0] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 3);
```

=>

```
0: [
    0: [
        0: MyStruct,
        1: MyStruct
    ],
    1: [
        0: MyStruct
    ],
    2: [
        0: MyStruct,
        1: MyStruct,
        2: MyStruct,
        3: MyStruct
    ]
],
1: [
    0: [
        0: MyStruct,
        1: MyStruct,
        2: MyStruct
    ]
]
```

Please correct me if there is something wrong, I wrote it freehand and I usually only write C++/C#.

Comment: Yes, the result should look like this JSON structure, but I you sure that in C it should be defined(allocated) the way you have done?

Comment: @Javier Hernández So why are you asking for an "Array" if u jsut want an Memoryobject? this is quite simple then....

Comment: @JavierHernández I am quite certain that it will work the way I did it, but I feel there is probably a better way. In C++ I would use a class, in C I do not know how to do it more sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

As far i got you right, and you want to store different sized structs in a 3d array i would do it this way:

```
typedef struct struct_s
{
    size_t sizeofElement;
    void *ptrToElement;
}struct_t;

void main(void)
{
    struct_t array[X][Y][Z];
    /*...*/
    array[x][y][z].ptrToElement = malloc (sizeof (structure));
    array[x][y][z].sizeofElement = sizeof (structure);

}
```

So you can handle with this array different sized Objects. and handle them right by asking for their size.

Edit:

Remember, you can't let the different dimmensions have different sizes, because

```
array[x][y][z];
```

is just requesting the memory as

```
void ***ptr = malloc (sizeof(type)*x + sizeof(type)*y + sizeof(type)*z;
```

would do.

so just split your own pointer up into

```
 void ***ptr = malloc (sizeof(type1)*x + sizeof(type2)*y + sizeof(type3)*z;
```

Comment: No, I tried to ask that one size structs are stored in 3d different sized arrays.

Comment: @Javier Hernández Then specify your Question, you jsut show a code snippet and talk about different sizes... your code snippet looks for me like you have an array of type `Mystructure* array [][][]` and you want each element to point to arrays of different size.... so why dontu make `Mystruct`have 2 elements, first as array of any type, and second the size of that element (as I already mentioned above...) So that would be the answer to the Question in the way you asked. And if i don't get the answer on stuff you didn't asked, im sorry about that, I'm not that good in Occlumency....